# How can I know where two rectangles intersected?

Tags: java, android, intersection, rectangles

I am having a problem with 2 rectangles intersection (one is bigger than other) in my android project. I used Rect.intersects(rect1,rect2) method, it works fine but I should know where it intersected. For example, rect1.right intersected with rect2.left etc. Is there any way to solve this problem?[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo32V.png)

I've written something like that to detect top or bottom. But it gives me mistakes by 2 or 5 pixels.

```
if (Rect.intersects(rect2,rect1)){
    //rect1 is smaller one
   if (rect1.exactCenterY()<rect2.exactCenterY() - rect2.height()/2||
      rect1.exactCenterY()>rect.exactCenterY() + rect2.height()/2){
      //It is top or bottom
         doSomething();
   }else{
         doSomething();
   }
}
```

I hope you guys will give me some advice or another way to solve it.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/MathUtils.java#38

Comment: Why are you using the center for calculations rather than the corners?

Comment: but if any math is making you a headache use `android.graphics.Region` API

Comment: @cricket_007 thought it was the fastest way. And idk what you mean.

Comment: You only need the top left and bottom right corners, plus the width and height to formulate a rectangle. Also, you're performing integer division against the height, which very likely is causing rounding issues of a few pixels

Comment: @pskink you mean i should use quickReject() instead of Rect.intersects()?

Comment: i think you should first try your math skills and use `MathUtils#constrain` method

Comment: or if you have two `Rect` objects (at least it seems to me you have) use `Rect#intersect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Thanks for advices. But important thing that you should also handle intersection for corners of rectangle.

```
if(rect2.setIntersects(rect2,rect1)){
    if(rect2.left!=rect1.left){
    //do something
    }else if(rect2.right!=rect1.right){
    //do something
    }// and so on
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rectangle class:

```
    int x = (int) rect1.intersection(rect2).getX();
    int y = (int) rect1.intersection(rect2).getY();
```

the method intersection returns the intersection rectangle. Read out that rectangle. Hope this helps.